# Constructor accepting (1) list of string; (2) array of str; (3) map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor

I would like to extend the constructor in such a way that the two lines with Level  and Color can be uncommented.
That is, one can generate an enum with a map and an enum with a list (this second is low priority).

I could renounce to the working (uncommnted) variant and accept only array, then check if the elements are strings or objects, but this solution wouldn't be as niche as the one I'm looking for (as long as it exists...).

```
class Enum {
  constructor (...values) {
    this.values = values;
    // this.map = None; 
  }

  check (value) {
    //if (this.map) {
    //  return this.map.keys().indexOf(value) !== -1;
    // } else {
      return this.values.indexOf(value) !== -1;
    // }

  }
}

const enums = {
  Size: new Enum('small', 'big', 'huge'),
  // Level: new Enum({'1': {txt: 'h1'}, '2': {txt: 'h2'}, '3': {txt: 'h3'}}),
  // Color: new Enum(['small', 'big', 'huge']),
};

export default enums;
```

Comment: In the second case, what should be `this.values`? As in, how would the `this.values.indexOf(value)` work?

Comment: Test `values[0]` to have be `typeof` string or `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Your object literal version has some syntax errors. I suspect you meant `new Enum({'1': {txt: 'h1'}, '2': {txt: 'h2'}, '3': {txt: 'h3'}})`?

Comment: @adiga In the second case `this.values` can be None to be clean, but it will just be ignored

Comment: @Bergi exactly, I'll correct the Q

Comment: @Bergi regarding your first comment, I understand; I'll try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Polymorphic" constructors is a bad idea mostly, because they are tricky to program (as you already know) and also harder to track down in the code. Instead, I'd suggest using specialized factory functions for every possible argument type. Example:

```js
class Enum {
    constructor(pairs) {
        for (let [name, val] of pairs)
            this[name] = val;
    }

    static from(names) {
        return new this([...names.entries()].map(([k, v]) => [v, k]));
    }

    static of(...names) {
        return this.from(names);
    }


    static fromObject(obj) {
        return new this(Object.entries(obj));
    }
}


const enums = {
    Size: Enum.of('small', 'big', 'huge'),
    Level: Enum.fromObject({'first': {txt: 'h1'}, 'second': {txt: 'h2'}, 'third': {txt: 'h3'}}),
    Color: Enum.from(['red', 'orange', 'blue']),
    Flags: new Enum([['read', 1], ['write', 2], ['execute', 4]])
};

console.log(enums.Size.huge)
console.log(enums.Color.orange)
console.log(enums.Level.third)
console.log(enums.Flags.execute)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `values[0]` is an Array. Then check if `values[0]` is an object. Not sure what the values should be for this scenario. The remaining scenario is for `Size`. In this case, directly assign `this.values = values`

```js
class Enum {

  constructor(...values) {
    if (Array.isArray(values[0]))
      this.values = values[0]
      
    else if (typeof values[0] === 'object')
      this.values = Object.keys(values[0]) // not sure
      
    else this.values = values;
  }

  check(value) {
    return this.values.indexOf(value) !== -1;
  }
}

const enums = {
    Size: new Enum('small', 'big', 'huge'),
    Level: new Enum({'1': {txt: 'h1'}, '2': {txt: 'h2'}, '3': {txt: 'h3'}}),
    Color: new Enum(['small', 'big', 'huge']),
};

console.log(enums)
```

Comment: For the array and object cases, one might also throw an exception if `values.length > 1` - just to catch accidental mistakes

Comment: Thank you. This solution do not preserve the dictionary, it extracts the keys. I did required it explicitly, but to save the extra information separately wouldn't be as nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with the help of @Bergi .

```js
class Enum {
  constructor (...keys) {
    this.keys = null;
    this.map = null;
    if (typeof keys[0] === 'string') {
      this.keys = keys;
    } else if (Array.isArray(keys[0])) {
      this.keys = keys[0];
    } else {
      this.map = keys[0];
    }
  }

  check (key) {
    if (this.keys != null) {
      return this.keys.indexOf(key) !== -1;
    } else if (this.map != null) {
      return key in this.map;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  value (key) {
    if (this.keys) {
      return (this.keys.indexOf(key) !== -1 ? key : null);
    } else if (this.map) {
      return (key in this.map ? this.map[key] : null);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const enums = {
  Size: new Enum('small', 'big', 'huge'),
  Color: new Enum(['red', 'green', 'blue']),
  Level: new Enum({
    '1': {
      text: 'h1',
    },
    '2': {
      text: 'h2',
    },
    '3': {
      text: 'h3',
    },
  }),
};

console.log(enums.Size.check('big'));
console.log(enums.Size.value('big'));
console.log(enums.Size.check('aaa'));
console.log(enums.Size.value('aaa'));
console.log(enums.Color.check('green'));
console.log(enums.Color.value('green'));
console.log(enums.Level.check('1'));
console.log(enums.Level.value('1').text);
console.log(enums.Level.check('8'));
console.log(enums.Level.value('8'));
```

Comment: I'd recommend to drop the `keys[0] instanceof String`. Nobody uses primitive wrapper instances, they are a considered a bad practice.